# UIScrollView Autoresizingmask programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to resize a UIScrollView programmatically to adjust the height when on a iPhone 5,  I have achieved this via the Storyboards but would like to do it programatically,

I've used done the following to create my UIScrollView but can't seem to change the size to suit the iPhone 5 is it because I'm initially setting the frame size for the smaller iPhones?

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 80, 289, 153)];
scroll.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
scroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: try, scroll.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 80, 289, 153)];
scroll.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but no joy, something is stopping the autoresize and keeping the frame at the set recmake size